# Calling Haskell from C with Cabal

Tags: c, haskell, cabal

I can't figure out how to build a C SDL application that calling Haskell with Foreign Function Interface, my main is in C, here is my .cabal file:

```
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  exposed-modules:     AI     

  other-extensions:    ForeignFunctionInterface
  build-depends:       base >=4.9 && <4.10
  hs-source-dirs:      src/haskell
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -O2 -shared -fPIC -dynamic 
  extra-libraries:     HSrts-ghc8.0.2
```

I followed the instructions in this [link](https://idontgetoutmuch.wordpress.com/2017/01/14/calling-haskell-from-c/) with no success(it's for OSX, not Linux).
I'm getting the Haskell source to build successfully with:

```
cabal install
```

But I can't figure out how to build the C code in such manner that Haskell will be recognized and imported into C.
Here is an example of my C and Haskell sources:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "game.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_error.h>
#include "HsFFI.h" // include path not recognized
#include "AI_stub.h" // new! edited

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    hs_init(&argc, &argv);
    //HASKELL CALL
    int i;
    i = fibonacci_hs(42);
    printf("Fibonacci: %d\n", i);
    //END HASKELL CALL
    initializeSdl();
    window = createWindow(SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    renderer = createRenderer();
    printf("Pre gameLoop\n"); 
    play();
    return 0;
}
```

AI.hs:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module AI where

import Foreign.C.Types

fibonacci :: Int -> Int
fibonacci n = fibs !! n
    where fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
fibonacci_hs = fromIntegral . fibonacci . fromIntegral

foreign export ccall fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
```

P.S:

- I am developing in ubuntu 18.04.
- GHC version is 8.0.2.
- Cabal version is 1.24.0.2.

Comment: Thanks for a well written question with a good [MCVE]

Comment: BTW, I think it should be `main-is: AI.hs` in the cabal file, not `AI.h`

Comment: My bad it is A.hs its a copy paste error, I've updated the question

Comment: Which compiler are you using to compile the `.c` file and what arguments are you giving it?

Comment: @Geraint Ballinger  gcc compiler, flags: `sdl2-config --libs --cflags` -ggdb3 -O0 --std=c99 -lSDL2_image -lm -Wall

Answer (score 2):

`HsFFI.h` is located in your Haskell installation folder. I'm using Windows and it is at `C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.4.3\lib\include`.

Also, when you build your Haskell module, a `.a` file should be generated. On my machine it is called `HSdll.dll.a`. (I have to rename it to `HSdll.a` in order to satisfy gcc, but I think it should be a Windows-specific issue.)

Then the following command will work:

`gcc -I"C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.4.3\lib\include" -L. -lHSdll main.c`

Note: change the `-I` to your haskell include folder and `-L.` to the place where the `.a` file is.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me but I used GHC instead of cabal:

([following this example](https://wiki.haskell.org/Calling_Haskell_from_C))

**First I compiled my Haskell library:**

```
ghc -c -O src/haskell/** -outputdir tmp
```

**Then I compiled with GHC:**

```
ghc --make `sdl2-config --libs --cflags` -optc-O src/c/*.c src/haskell/*.hs -no-hs-main -outputdir tmp -lSDL2_image -o targetLinux/myExecutable
```

**Where:**

- src/c Is my c sources directory.
- src/haskell Is my Haskell sources directory.
- tmp Is my object files folder (all of *.o files).

Although I have no clue how to build the entire project including c sources with cabal.

Comment: Is there a reason why you instructed GHC to compile the Haskell code into a dynamic shared library in your original question but not in this answer?

Comment: @GeraintBallinger I had trouble using the generated library, maybe I'll give it another go.